# Is there a way to replace a substring with a same amount of X characters the length of it?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match some strings in a file with Perl with a regular expression that would susbtitute them with an equal amount of X characters, long like the original string length.
For instance the file could contain something like:

```
"the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world" etc. etc.
```

and a dictionary that for instance has the strings like: `"hello world"` and that I would load into an array before.

I'd like to have the following result:

```
"the quick brown XXXXX XXXXX fox jumps over the world" etc. etc.
```

Comment: Depending on your use case please don't forget to read this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/

Comment: You should tag your question with the requested programming language

Comment: you need design algorithm....

get all dictionary words in array.

create a dictionary copy, and replace all characters with X (not spaces).
make a loop for test in string each word in dictionary( strpos() ), if it is found replace with masked string  (str_replace).

Comment: @rubenrp81 "Badge your question" ?

Comment: your language is php?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: well I admit you are perfectly right, but the idea is to filter out some strings from a document automatically indeed but then review them by a human being since what is described as obscenity filters does really make sense.. :)

Comment: I'm also thinking that it will probably be even more difficult than I was thinking originally since I'd need to mach the dictionary strings not only one line after the other of the file but the dictionary string could also be line-wrapped like in: "the quick brown hello" \n "world fox jumps over the world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a substution with the `/e` modifier for an *expression replacement*, together with the repetition operator `x`

The code looks like this. The `\Q` ... `\E` construct is to escape any non-alphanumeric characters so that they are interpreted literally instead of as regex metacharacters

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world';

my $pattern = 'hello world';

$s =~ s/(\Q$pattern\E)/'X' x length $1/e;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
the quick brown XXXXXXXXXXX fox jumps over the world
```

---

#### Update

If you want to keep the whitespace in the replaced string then you need two nested expression replacements, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

use Data::Dump;

my $s = 'the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world';

my $pattern = 'hello world';

$s =~ s{(\Q$pattern\E)}{ s/(\S+)/'x' x length($1)/egr }e;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
the quick brown xxxxx xxxxx fox jumps over the world
```

or, if you are running a very old version of Perl (prior to v5.14) then you need this

```
$s =~ s{(\Q$pattern\E)}{ (my $r = $1) =~ s/(\S+)/'x' x length($1)/eg; $r }e;
```

Comment: @tent: If you are replacing English words then you will probably want to at least wrap your regex in `\b`...`\b` (wound boundary anchors) to avoid embarrxxxment

Comment: do you mean like this:
$s =~ s/(\b\Q$pattern\E\b)/'X' x length $1/e;
because they are always going to be in boundaries and never nested indeed..
And by the way: would it be possible to do the match also between multiple lines (I'm going to read $s from a file containing many lines and the pattern might occur line-wrapped but always only on the whitespace)

Comment: @tent: Yes. I was thinking of `s/\b(\Q$pattern\E)\b/'X' x length $1/e` but yours is fine

Comment: And by the way: would it be possible to do the match also between multiple lines (I'm going to read $s from a file containing many lines and the pattern might occur line-wrapped but always only on the whitespace)

Comment: @tent you would have to use `\s+` in the pattern instead of spaces

Comment: I just noticed that the use of /Q /E seems problematic since the pattern sometimes contains also parentheses () or quotes.. so not only alphanumerics.. leaving /Q /E out does not seem to solve either..

Comment: @tent: I don't understand. `\Q` will escape parentheses so that they are matched literally. Quotes aren't special inside regex patterns anyway, so escaping them makes no difference. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

No.

However, your language might have a regex-replace function that accepts a callback. Then you could do something like this:

```
>>> re.sub(r'o+b', lambda m: 'x' * len(m.group(0)), 'foobar')
'fxxxar'
```

Comment: ***"No."*** I challenge that solution

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant than ThiefM's answer (Python):

```
import re
str_to_replace = 'hello world'
print re.sub(str_to_replace, re.sub('\w', 'x', str_to_replace), \
    "the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world")

# another option 
print "the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world".replace(str_to_replace, re.sub('\w', 'x', str_to_replace))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
the quick brown xxxxx xxxxx fox jumps over the world
```

PHP solution for @rubenrp81:

```
<?php
$msg = "the quick brown hello world fox jumps over the world";
$str = "hello world";
$rep = preg_replace("/\w/", "x", $str);
$patt = "/$str/";
$res = preg_replace($patt, $rep, $msg);
echo $res; // prints: "the quick brown xxxxx xxxxx fox jumps over the world"
?>
```

Comment: @rubenrp81 this is python. BTW, how did you conclude that it's for PHP ?

Comment: @rubenrp81 LOL, here's a PHP solution for you ;)